# SVG path with a blank command

Tags: svg

SVG's path defines several commands (`M`, `m`, `L`, `l`, `z`, etc). However I sometime see missing/blank commands, e.g.

```
m 0,0 20,0 0,20 -20,0 z
```

It would appear that no command is a line command but I can't find this documented anywhere. Is this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is documented at several places in the SVG specification

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#paths-PathData

> The command letter can be eliminated on subsequent commands if the same command is used multiple times in a row (e.g., you can drop the second "L" in "M 100 200 L 200 100 L -100 -200" and use "M 100 200 L 200 100 -100 -200" instead).

and also under the explanation of the  M command:

> If a moveto is followed by multiple pairs of coordinates, the subsequent pairs are treated as implicit lineto commands.